# Finding the mass of a region limited by these surfaces:

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the mass of the region E limited by the following conditions:

z(x² + y²) = 2 (is this a paraboloid equation?)
z = 0
x² + y² = 1
x² + y² = 2
x greater than or equal to 0
0 greater than or equal to y
m is the volumetric density of E and is constant and equal to 1.

My first idea was to make 2z-¹ = u and write the problem in cylindrical coordinates then. But if z = 0, then there'll be a discontinuity in the surface and I'm not sure about taking the limit of this expression as b approaches infinity.

Thanks in advance! I'm not sure about how to sketch the first condition (z(x² + y²) = 2), though...

Comment: just wondering how this turned out?

Comment: It worked fine for me! Thank you so much, I'm studying for my finals, that's why I haven't given you feedback sooner. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, best of luck on your finals. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, the region of integration ranges from $r=1$ to $r=2$ and from $\theta = -{\pi\over 2}$ to $0$, with a "ceiling" given by $z = {2\over r^2}$. The mass/volume element is a wedge $dV = r dr d\theta dz$. So we have
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0{\int_{r=1}^2{\int_{z=0}^{2\over r^2}{r dr d\theta dz}}}\,.$$

Your idea to use cylindrical coordinates was a good one. Where I think you might be getting confused is that you seem to be making some kind of simultaneous requirement that $z(x^2+y^2)=2$ and $z=0$. These are not simultaneous equations---indeed, plug $z=0$ into the first equation and you get the absurdity $0=2$. Rather, $z=0$ is the "floor" and $z=2/(x^2+y^2)$ is the "ceiling."

To get a visual sense of what the ceiling looks like, graph ${2\over r^2}$ and rotate the curve around the vertical axis.